# Silverlight passing the value from view to ViewModel MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

Hi I have a textbox with a text that is initially populated to a value through Data Binding.

```
    <TextBox Name="EmployeeName" Text="{Binding Employee.Name}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
```

And I have a refresh button that should reset it back to its original value and a Save button that should save the changes.

```
    <Button Name="RefreshEmployeeName" Content="Refresh" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="25" Command="{Binding RefreshEmployeeNameCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=EmployeeName}"/>

    <Button Name="SaveEmployeeName" Content="Refresh" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="25" Command="{Binding SaveEmployeeNameCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=EmployeeName}"/>
```

I am using MVVM lightand in my View Model I have created 2 RelayCommands

```
    SaveEmployeeNameCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveEmployee);

    RefreshEmployeeNameCommand = new RelayCommand(RefreshEmployee);

    private void SaveEmployee()
    {
```

// how to get the value from the text box (Command Parameter) here
         }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to pass the name as a CommandParameter. As long as the employee's Name property has a public setter and you use a two-way binding on the text box, you can get the employee's name using this.Employee.Name.

Comment: I Have the Employee as public Parameter in my View Model. In my SaveEmplyee function. this.Employee.Name does not give the changed value of the textbox. Can you please elaborate the solution.

Comment: Try <TextBox Name="EmployeeName" Text="{Binding Employee.Name, Mode=TwoWay}...". The binding should update Employee.Name for you whenever the text box loses focus.

Comment: How can I reset the changed value to its original value on clicking reset button.